# Finding a closed form for sum of upper nearest powers of $3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Suppose that $c_n$ is the smallest power of $3$ greater than or equal
>   to $n$. Can we find a closed form for:
>
> $$S_n=c_1+c_2+...+c_n\ ?$$

I think this sequence is similar to the ceiling function, I wrote a few terms

$$\underbrace{1}_{1},\underbrace{3,3}_2,\underbrace{9,9,9,9,9,9}_6,\underbrace{27,27,...,27}_{18},81,81,...$$

but I could not see by what factor the number of powers of three in the sequence increases. And another problems seems to be that if $n$ is not a power of three, the sequence ends abruptly without completing the subsequence. Is it possible to finds a closed formula in this case?

Comment: When $n=3^k$ for $k$ an integer, you get $S_n = \frac{3^{2k+1}+1}{4}.$ If $3^k\leq n<3^{k+1}$ then $$S_n = (n-3^k)3^{k+1} + \frac{3^{2k+1}+1}{4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$c_n$ satisfies $3^k < c_n \leq 3^{k+1}$, so there will be $3^{k+1}-3^k$ terms of every power of three. If $n=3^p$, for some positive integer $p$, you get

$$
\begin{aligned}
S_{3^p}&=3^0+\sum_{k=1}^p\left(3^k-3^{k-1}\right)3^k\\
&=3^0+\sum_{k=1}^k2\cdot 3^{k-1} \cdot 3^k\\
&= 3^0+6\cdot \sum_{k=1}^k 3^{2(k-1)}\\
&=1+6\cdot \frac{3^{2p}-1}{3^2-1}\\
&=\frac{3^{2p+1}+1}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$

If $n = 3^p+q$, then you just have to add those 'incomplete' powers of $3$ as well:

$$S_{3^p+q}=S_{3^p}+q\cdot 3^{p+1}=\frac{3^{2p+1}+1}{4}+q\cdot 3^{p+1}$$

The final answer will be:

$$S_n=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{3^{2p+1}+1}{4}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ when }n = 3^p\\
\dfrac{3^{2p+1}+1}{4}+q\cdot 3^{p+1},\ \text{ when }n=3^p+q
\end{cases}$$